# How to get package name in apt hooks?

Tags: apt

I created the following hook in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`:

```
Dpkg::Pre-Invoke {"/etc/apt/log.sh";};
```

Contents of `/etc/apt/log.sh` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$@" | tee -a /etc/apt/my.log
```

When I (re)install some package, I expect to have that package name and the command as parameters, but there is no such parameter passed to the hook script.

How can I get installed package(s) name(s) within the hook script?

Answer (score 1):

`DPkg::Pre-Invoke` is a very general hook which isn’t tied to specific package operations; as a result it doesn’t provide a way to obtain the list of packages being operated on.

To get a list of installed packages, you should use `DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkg` instead. There is some documentation [in the `apt` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/apt/apt.conf.5#HOW_APT_CALLS_DPKG(1)), but you’ll probably need to experiment. Commands run by this hook receive the list of packages on their standard input by default, with varying levels of detail depending on the protocol being used. Note that this hook is also invoked when removing packages, so your handler will have to check the action corresponding to each package.

Setting the protocol isn’t obvious from the documentation; in `DPkg::Tools::options::cmd::Version`, replace `cmd` with your command. See for example `apt-listbugs`, which adds

```
DPkg::Tools::Options::/usr/sbin/apt-listbugs::Version "3";
```

to specify version 3 of the protocol.

[muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) wrote up a comprehensive example [on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006704/412264) which should make things clearer.

Comment: I did this for a post over [ubuntu.se], OP might find the examples useful: https://askubuntu.com/a/1006704/158442